# Uploading files images,videos,zip,etc.Is it possible in new fire-base and how to do in rest API

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-storage

Uploading files images,videos,zip,etc is it possible in new fire-base and how to do in rest API.I selected the FLAME method in fire-base. I wanna send and retrieve image and files in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Storage is a iOS/Android/Web service that wraps Google Cloud Storage. Firebase Storage allows client devices to access GCS in a secure, reliable manner

While Firebase Storage doesn't have a REST API, Google Cloud Storage does. See the [documentation for the Google Cloud Storage REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-guide).

Comment: Good explanation.Is there any other storage frameworks with good performance